# Сохранение текста в файл из RichTexBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема:
на форме есть два RichTextBox, в обоих есть текст с определённым форматированием (т.е. некоторые строки пропущены и т.д.). Мне нужно сохранить оба текста в файл так, чтобы форматирование в полученном файле сохранилось.
Пробовал PrintWriter - он форматирование губит (всё в одну строчку делает).
Пробовал SaveFileDialog - он, кажись, сохраняет только из одного текстового поля (как прикрутить два не нашёл).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поступить.
Спасибо.

Comment: Всё, спасибо...сам разобрался...извратно, но всё же...)
Вопрос закрыт...)

Да, если у кого-нибудь есть решение данной проблемы с помощью PrintWriter, то прошу...буду весьма благодарен...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой способ - это сохранять значение каждого RichTextBox в свой файл формата RTF с помощью SaveFile

```
rtb1.SaveFile(fileName1)
rtb2.SaveFile(fileName2)
```

Если нужно вывести содержимое нескольких элементов в один файл, то

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, rtb1.Lines);
File.AppendAllLines(fileName, rtb2.Lines);
```

либо получить строки с форматированием, объединить и вывести

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, rtb1.rtf + rtb2.rtf);
```

Comment: Круто...помогло...)
Спасибо...)

Только проблема: File.AppendAllLines(fileName, rtb2.Lines); только в 4-ом Framework'е...)

Поэтому объединил две строчки и сделал File.WriteAllLines();